# Integrated video card is not detected in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, integrated-graphics

I have dual monitor setup powered by NVidia GTS 9800 with 2xDVI.

Found the third monitor and tried to plug it in via the integrated graphics card (the DVI connected on the board) as a video source for it - but no luck at all - Windows 7 does not seems to be detecting the integrated card.

I have the enabled the integrated video in the BIOS (motherboard is GA-MA785GT-UD3H) - but it didn't seem to change anything.

Is there any way to get Windows 7 see the integrated graphics?

Cheers

Comment: On occasion, you won't be able to use an integrated graphics card at the same time as your add-in card.  This is especially true with AGP and what not where you only had one "slot" that could either be used by the on-board card, or an add-in, but not both.  Go back into your BIOS and set the on-board as primary, if there is such an option.  Also, be sure to connect a monitor to it before booting up.

Comment: What @Brad said - I'm not familiar with this motherboard, but a lot of motherboards simply Won't Let You Do This™.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion of an add in Video card disables the onboard video, no workaround either, it is a bios level restriction on most all Motherboards.